# StateClient reference not found in Microsoft.Bot.Connector v4.0.1

Tags: c#, botframework

I have been using Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3.x all this time to develop Bot.
I have started using Microsoft.Bot.Builder v4.x to develop Bots, I made use of Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Classic to shift v3.0 bot solution to v4.0 bot solution.

I have come across one issue where I need to use StateClient object found within Microsoft.Bot.Connector v3.11.1 but I cannot find the same in Microsoft.Bot.Connector v4.0.1 which I cannot depricate since I have moved to Microsoft.Bot.Builder v4.x.

I need StateClient as I am moving authentication token(and few more data) from an MVC application to my Bot using StateClient and BotData.

```
StateClient _stateClient = result.GetStateClient();
BotState _botState = new BotState(_stateClient);
BotData _botData = await _botState.GetUserDataAsync(result.ChannelId, 
result.From.Id);
string _token = _botData.GetProperty<string>("AccessToken");
```

Comment: I seem to recall that StateClient has been deprecated. I can't find the announcement, but [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/03/29/accessing-a-net-bots-state-via-dependency-injection/) refers to it, saying _"The .NET BotBuilder SDK has deprecated the StateClient class, leaving some to wonder how they should access their bot’s state."_ and links to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2018/02/13/accessing-a-dotnet-bots-state-via-dependency-injection/)

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327229/how-to-store-retrieve-bot-data-in-azure-table-storage-with-directline-channel)

Comment: I did see these things, wondering there should have been some alternative

Comment: I believe you have to implement your own storage, for example in Azure Table stoarge as per the answer to the linked question.

Comment: exactly, hoping someone may have found some alternative

Comment: That **is** the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using `StateClient`. There is no alternative, it's deprecated (for a while now).

Alternatives are clearly listed in the documentation page called "Manage state data" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=azure-bot-service-3.0). It takes a few minutes to switch to Azure Cosmos DB or Table Storage, then you can use `UserData`, `ConversationData` or `PrivateConversationData` again.