# How can we log user-bot conversations using the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I am starting to create my first bot with Microsoft Bot Framework with the help of Azure, initially I want to know where all the conversations the user has with the bot are stored, so then get a log of all the conversations that have been held.

I already have some answers stored in knowledge bases using QnA Maker, for certain questions that you can answer, I want to know where the questions that were not answered or better that the bot could not answer are stored.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure QnaMaker to log questions and answers to application insights then use the built-in analytics to query it.
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base)

Answer (score 0):

Conversation data is not stored by default, but you can configure your Bot to store conversation data using different methods.

One way is using a Cosmos DB - [Save conversation history from MS bot to cosmos db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241179/save-conversation-history-from-ms-bot-to-cosmos-db)

Another is using REST and a SharePoint List - [Save question when no answer is available for that question (new question) in QnA Maker Knowledge Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904731/save-question-when-no-answer-is-available-for-that-question-new-question-in-qn/56906132#56906132)